# How to structure vectorized function with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I am unsure how to structure a function I want to vectorize in pandas.

I have two df's like such:

```py
contents = pd.DataFrame({
'Items': [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2],
})

cats = pd.DataFrame({
'Cat1': ['1|2|4'],
'Cat2': ['3|2|5'],
'Cat3': ['6|9|11'],
})
```

My goal is to `.insert` a new column to `contents` that, per row, is either `1` if `contents['Items']` is element of `cats['cat1']` or `0` otherwise. That is to be repeated per `cat`.

Goal format:

```py
contents = pd.DataFrame({
'Items': [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2],
'contains_Cat1': [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
'contains_Cat2': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
'contains_Cat3': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
})
```

As my contents df is big(!) I would like to vectorize this. My approach for each cat is to do something like this

```py
contents.insert(
    loc=len(contents.columns),
    column='contains_Cat1',
    value=has_content(contents, cats['Cat1'])

def has_content(contents: pd.DataFrame, cat: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    # Initialization of pd.Series here??
    if contents['Items'] in cat:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

My question is: How do I structure my `has_content(...)`? Especially unclear to me is how I initialize that pd.Series to contain all `False` values. Do I even need to? After that I know how to check if something is contained in something else. But can I really do it column-wise like above and return immediately without becoming cell-wise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple method:**

```
contents = (contents.join([pd.Series(contents.Items.astype(str).
                                     str.contains(cats[c][0]).astype(int), 
                                     name="Contains_"+c) for c in cats]))
```

---

**contents:**

```
    Items   contains_Cat1   contains_Cat2   contains_Cat3
0   1       1               0               0
1   2       1               1               0
2   3       0               1               0
3   1       1               0               0
4   1       1               0               0
5   2       1               1               0
```

---

Time comparison:

```
%%timeit -n 2000
(contents.join([pd.Series(contents.Items.astype(str).
                                     str.contains(cats[c][0]).astype(int), 
                                     name="Contains_"+c) for c in cats]))
```

> 3.01 ms ± 344 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 2000 loops each)

---

```
%%timeit -n 2000
cats.stack().str.get_dummies().stack()\
          .unstack(level=1).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)\
           .reindex(contents.Items.astype(str))
```

> 5.13 ms ± 584 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 2000 loops each)

---

```
%%timeit -n 2000
cats.stack().str.get_dummies().droplevel(0).T\
        .add_prefix('contains_').reindex(contents['Items'].astype(str)).reset_index()
```

> 4.58 ms ± 512 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 2000 loops each)

Answer (score 5):

Try with `str.get_dummies` then reshape with `stack` and `unstack`

```
out = cats.stack().str.get_dummies().stack()\
          .unstack(level=1).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)\
           .reindex(contents.Items.astype(str))
Out[229]: 
       Cat1  Cat2  Cat3
Items                  
1         1     0     0
2         1     1     0
3         0     1     0
1         1     0     0
1         1     0     0
2         1     1     0
```

**Improvement:**

```
out=cats.stack().str.get_dummies().droplevel(0).T\
        .add_prefix('contains_').reindex(contents['Items'].astype(str)).reset_index()

Out[230]: 

    Items   contains_Cat1   contains_Cat2   contains_Cat3
0   1       1               0               0
1   2       1               1               0
2   3       0               1               0
3   1       1               0               0
4   1       1               0               0
5   2       1               1               0
```

Comment: Just to clarify: I'm getting a df returned here, right? So I skip the .insert() and the separate function altogether?